# How to parse json response in android which is of the following format

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json response in android for my android application. I am getting `org.json.JSONException`. The response is as shown below:

```
 {
    id: "12345"
    email:"abc@gmail.com"
firstName:"abcd"
lastName:"efgh"
userName:"abc123"
    }
```

I am trying to parse the response as shown below:

```
 if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(text);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                       JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(response.toString());

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                             id = c.getString("_id");
                             email = c.getString("email");
                             firstName = c.getString("firstName");
                             lastName = c.getString("lastName");
                             userName = c.getString("userName");
 }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Can any one let me know what mistake am I doing in parsing the response. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I guess there should be comma's between your JSON attributes?

Comment: where is array node ? See my answer below please

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this you are using "_id" instead of "id"

```
id = c.getString("id");
email = c.getString("email");
firstName = c.getString("firstName");
lastName = c.getString("lastName");
userName = c.getString("userName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this `id = c.getString("_id");` to `id = c.getString("id");`

in the future, you may show error in logcat when parsing like this:

```
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I can think of , first of all  you should get to know that what are []  , {}  . The square brackets are arrays in json and curly demonstrate the object , so I think you are casting it wrong

**1>**

> JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(response.toString()); "this is culprit"

You should change it to

> JSONObject. Use JSONObject in place of JSONArray

and Secondly

**2> change this key  id = c.getString("_id");to**

> id = c.getString("id");

Make sure You are getting and writing spellings of all keys right else it would generate exception.